# How to read the table metadata information from Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to read the below table metadata info from JAVA. Any suggestion to do this
With ResultsetMetadata only few data can be retrieved not all the below as stated..

**columnName**="PAYTRXKEY" **dataType**="NUMBER" **Primarykey**="N" **length**="22" **nullable**="N" **precision**="14" **scale**="0" **default**="None" **sequence**="1"

Comment: Also what is not in metadata has to be read from database system tables and that depends on database you are using

Comment: @piro I am using Oracle database, And with DatabaseMetadata, ResultsetMetaData, we can read only the base info. how about the Nullable check, default values, Column order. how to read these information.

Comment: You can find this in the system tables such as dba_constraints, if you have the privilege to read it.

Comment: Thanks all
I am able to retrieve the info..